# counter start on specific div scroll in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can start counter on scroll event.

```
var count = 0;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 40);
    function timer(){
        count += 1;
        if(count == 98){
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = count;
    }
```

html code

```
<h3><span id="num">98</span>+</h3>
```

Comment: What is your question? Can't you ask a question instead of repeating the same word

Comment: Can you edit the question so that other people too get the help from the question you are asking, if it is interesting. Read the help page of the site. How to ask a question and reply to the question is clearly written there.

Comment: Start a function on Scroll Using javascript on specific div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of what you are trying to do..

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            #myScroller {
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: beige;
                display: block;
                overflow-y:auto; 

            }

            #demo {
                margin: 10px;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: bisque;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="myScroller" class="test">
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
            <br>Test
        </div>

        <div id="demo"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myScroller  = document.getElementById("myScroller"),
                demo = document.getElementById("demo");
                myScroller.addEventListener("scroll", function(){

                    var count = 0;
                    var counter = setInterval(timer, 40);
                    function timer() {
                        count += 1;
                        if(count == 98){
                            clearInterval(counter);
                        }
                        demo.innerHTML = count;
                    }
                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

this works in ie >= 9, firefox, opera, chrome

Comment: Hey PHJCJO. i solved this by my self.. Thank you for your help also..var count = 0;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 40);
    function timer(){
        if(window.pageYOffset > 1700){
        count += 1;
        }if(count == 98){
            clearInterval(counter);
        }
        document.getElementById('num').innerHTML = count;
    }